# KDB+ Historical Database Partitioning Strategy

Tags: kdb

My dataset is 2.5 billion rows; minutely data on roughly 30,000 securities.

I'm able to stream this data into a splayed database, however, simple queries like `select from data where sym=AAPL` **take ages** and frequently crash KDB with out of memory (32GB RAM).

I'm running q with 16 slave processes (8 cores, 16 with hyperthreading). If I use
compression (IPC or zlib), I can't query anything without crashing.

2.5bn rows doesn't seem like very much by modern standards, so I'm struggling how best to approach this. I don't really want to partition by date; should I partition by symbol?

I'll want to do queries like `desc select sum volume by sym, t.date`, amongst others.

I can of course, subdivide the dataset, but honestly it would be easier to keep all the data together.

What's the canonical thing to do here?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to partition by date? The fact you have `t.date` in your example query would indicate a date partitioning scheme would be beneficial here

Answer (score 0):

A partitioned database with attributes applied will be a better way to manage that data.

- https://code.kx.com/q/kb/partition/
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/set-attribute/
- https://kx.com/blog/partitioning-data-in-kdb/
- https://code.kx.com/q/wp/columnar-database/
- https://code.kx.com/q/wp/query-scaling/
- https://code.kx.com/q/wp/data-management/

Ensuring the partitioned column is first in clauses will ensure map-reduce logic is triggered to minimize memory usage

- https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb%2B/#1437-map-reduce